# git log, show files for specific username and branch

Tags: git

I'd like to combine git log and git show so that I can list all changes files for a given user, for a given branch. My aim is to be able to see what files I have personally changes, over the life of a branch (as opposed to files changes in my branch from a merge)

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to list the names of the changed files or the changes themselves as well? What do you mean by "files changes in my branch from a merge"? A branch always contains all the commits from any merges into it. I think I could answer your question if it were more concrete.

Comment: `git log` lets you pass in a format... You can grep through the result by author.... Take a peak at git man page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit `log` output to a given author and/or committer

```
git log --author=my_username
```

You can have log give the history of a branch simply by naming the branch, but be aware this alone may not to *exactly* what you expect (see below):

```
git log --author=my_username my_branch
```

The thing is, this will list all commits *reachable from* the branch.  (A branch is a pointer to a single commit; log then follows "parent commit" pointers (by default) to provide a history for the branch.

That will include commits that, perhaps, you think are "on the parent branch" rather than "on this branch".  For example

```
A -- B -- C -- D <--(master)
      \
       E -- F <--(my_branch)
```

Here all of `A`, `B`, `E` and `F` are reachable from `my_branch`.  So if you think of `A` and `B` as "not on the branch", you need something more.  And what that is depends on the situation, because the idea of commits "on a particular branch" (rather than "reachable from any number of branches") is an artificial concept users like to impose on git, but that git doesn't really know about.

In the above case, you would say

```
git log --author=my_username master..my_branch
```

to exclude anything reachable from `master`, leaving `E` and `F` only (and filtering those based on author info).

Lastly, you appear to want to see the patch from each change.  (You said "combine with `show`".)  So you could use `-p`:

```
git log -p --author=my_username master..my_branch
```

Or if you decide you'd rather list the files instead

```
git log --name-only --author=my_username master..my_branch
```

Comment: Hi, it's saying author is not a valid option

Comment: Looks like I have some typos (where I said `-` instead of `--`).  Updated.  The correct way to start any full-word option is `--`.  Beyond that I know no reason why the option wouldn't be recognized; I've tested this approach in writing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a git alias that I use; If I understand the question, I think this does what you want.

```
if $(git rev-parse --verify --quiet $1 >/dev/null); then
    COMMIT=$1;
    shift;
else
    COMMIT=HEAD;
fi;
git log "$@" $(git merge-base origin/master $COMMIT)..$COMMIT;
```

Usage: `git <alias_name> [commit] [extra_args]`, so I would do `git lo --author="John Doe"`.  You can add extra `git log` arguments like `-p` and `--stat` to find the information you are looking for.